# Python: How to create a dictionary named after a list entry?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to python so this is probably a dumb question. I'm sure the answer is in the docs or another thread on stack overflow, but I could not find it.

I have a list: `dict_list = ['first_dict', 'second_dict', 'third_dict']`

I need a way create a dictionary for each entry in this list and then reference it later using its list index. So, by referencing `dict_list[0]`, I want to be able to create a new dictionary `first_dict = {}`.

Then, I want to be able to reference that dictionary again later by using `dict_list[0]`, then assign keys and values to first_dict.

This `dict_list` will contain anywhere from 1 to 1000 entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you need the names for? The answer is, you don't. When you start thinking about programmatically assigning a bunch of variable names, especially if those names have numbers in them, you are almost always better off just making a list or some other container.

```
dict_list = [{} for x in xrange(3)]
```

Now `dict_list[0]` is one dictionary, `dict_list[1]` is another, and so on. This makes them easy to iterate over and access without hackery like `globals()` or `eval()`.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `globals()`:

```
In [54]: dict_list = ['first_dict', 'second_dict', 'third_dict']

In [55]: for x in dict_list:
    globals()[x]=dict()
   ....:     
   ....:     

In [57]: dict_list=[globals()[x] for x in dict_list]

In [58]: dict_list[0]['key']='value'  #add key to first_dict 

In [60]: first_dict       
Out[60]: {'key': 'value'}

In [63]: first_dict is dict_list[0]  #dict_list[0] and first_dict are same objects
Out[63]: True
```